# Empty Body HTTP Post request Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, post

I am trying to send a Post request but the body of the request is meant to be empty and I have tried the endpoint on postman with an empty body and it works.

But now I don't know how to implement that on Flutter.

I know how to create post requests with body. But I don't know how to make the post with an empty body.

```
Future<http.Response> createAlbum() {
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse(BASE_URL),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      
    }),
  );
}
```

when the response body is empty the `response.statusCode` is 500

Comment: the album dont have a POST request. If you check carefully on \posts have an HTTP POST method.

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: that part is just a sample code.. not the actual. I am asking if it possible to send post request with empty body. I've edited the question

Comment: As per my understanding, you are still able to send post request with empty body and receiving an error code from backend. So you check backend program not to send 404 instead accept your request.

Comment: Use `body: Uint8List(0),` but note that then your content type is likely wrong since an empty body wouldn't have a JSON type.

Comment: this doesn't work @RichardHeap

Comment: @RaghuMudem the status code is 500 now. When I make the post request on postman without a body it works. But I can't achieve that on flutter

Comment: Update the question showing the working postman request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, http allows an empty parameter to be passed as the argument to a body.

```
var response = await client.post(
        uri,
        body: jsonEncode({}),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<http.Response> createAlbum() {
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse(BASE_URL),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
     body: jsonEncode("{}"),
  );
}
```